# Factory method C++ implementation

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I was wondering if this piece of code does everything the **pure factory method** design pattern asks for? This is in preparation for my final programming module and I just need to make sure that is is the correct application of the design pattern.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

class Bread
{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class WhiteBread: public Bread
{
public:
    void print() {
        qDebug() << "White bread";
    }
};

class BrownBread: public Bread
{
public:
    void print() {
        qDebug() << "Brown bread";
    }
};

class BreadFactory {
public:
    Bread* makeBread(QString type) {
        if (type == "White bread")
            return new WhiteBread();
        else if (type == "Brown bread")
            return new BrownBread();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    BreadFactory *breadFactory = new BreadFactory();
    Bread *breadType;

    breadType= breadFactory->makeBread("White bread");
    breadType->print();

    breadType = breadFactory->makeBread("Brown bread");
    breadType->print();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I think this is called 'abstract factory method'. If that's what's meant, its OK. But if really 'pure' (pure virtual) is meant, then you should probably have an abstract ancestor class with a pure virtual (without a body) factory method and two inheriting concrete classes with implementations for that method with the same signature (including abstract return type) but creating objects of different derived classes of the abstract return type of the factory method.

Comment: Yours is a simplified variation of the factory method and it is not practically useful. What if a new derived object yellow_bread has to be included without changing the factory class code. You need a method in the factory that allows registration of objects dynamically.

Comment: btw, missing virtual destructor, not all path of makeBread return. and `unique_ptr` would be better than raw pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, so should I create an abstract bread factory that handles the logic and a client that creates an abstract factory? Could anyone give me an example of this implementation? I don't have much experience in OOP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need to make instance `BreadFactory`. Just use static method.

   ```
   class BreadFactory
   {
       public:
           static Bread* makeBread( QString type ) 
           {
           ...
           }
   };

   //in main 
   Bread *breadType = BreadFactory::makeBread( "White Bread"); 
   breadType->print();
   ```
2. Use c++11 `override` keyword, for clarity.

   ```
   class WhiteBread : public Bread
   {
   public:
       void print() override{
   ...
   ```
3. Use c++11 `unique_ptr` among smart pointer.

   ```
   static unique_ptr<Bread> makeBread( QString type ) {
       if ( type == "White bread" )
           return std::make_unique<WhiteBread>();
       else if ( type == "Brown bread" )
           return std::make_unique<BrownBread>();
       else
           return nullptr;
   }
   ```
4. Use `virtual` destructor.

   ```
   class Bread
   {
   public:
       virtual void print() = 0;
       virtual ~Bread() {};
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A Factory Method implementation would be like this:

```
class BreadMaker
{
 public:
   virtual Bread* makeBread() = 0;
}

class WhiteBreadMaker : public BreadMaker
{
public:
   Bread* makeBread();
}

// WhiteBreadMaker.cpp
Bread* WhiteBreadMaker::makeBread()
{
   return new WhiteBread();
}

// ***Similarly for BrownBreadMaker

// main.cpp
int main()
{
   BreadMaker *maker = new WhiteBreadMaker();    // or BrownBreadMaker

   Bread *bread = maker->makeBread();
   bread->print();    // prints "White Bread" or "Brown Bread" depending on the Factory class used.
}
```